# GitLab pipeline strange failure, even on an old, previously "green" commit

Tags: docker, testing, rabbitmq, gitlab-ci

I'm experiencing a very strange problem with [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/) CI: I have a JVM based *pet project* with end-to-end tests that use [EventStore](https://eventstore.org/), [MongoDb](https://www.mongodb.com/) and [RabbitMq](https://www.rabbitmq.com/), so a few months ago I configured `.gitlab-ci-yml` defining a couple of `services`: my e2e tests run against them and every worked well.

A few days ago I made some changes to my project, pushed to GitLab and the pipeline has failed, due the fact that my e2e test do not seem to receive the correct number of messages from RabbitMq.
After a few days of investigation I gathered some information:

- the e2e test run without errors on two different local machines (in my IDE)
- the same test fails systematically on the GitLab pipeline
- the failing test fails due to a *wrong* number of received messages, **but** the *wrong* number never changes: the error seems to be *deterministic*
- the e2e test run without errors launching it locally through `gitlab-runner` (same 12.5.0 version as in the remote pipeline execution)
- if I start the pipeline execution from an old commit, for which the pipeline ran without errors months ago, **the pipeline fails**: same commit, same code, same `services` configuration in `.gitlab-ci.yml`, but the pipeline is now red (and it was green a few months ago)
- in order to exclude any strange dependencies from the Docker `latest` tag, I fixed one of the services I'm using, specifying the version-tag explicitly: same result, remote pipeline red but local execution through `gitlab-runner` green
- my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file is available [here](https://gitlab.com/darwinsw/event.boss/blob/issues/2-3-naming-strategies/.gitlab-ci.yml)
- example of pipeline execution for an old commit can be found [here (green)](https://gitlab.com/darwinsw/event.boss/-/jobs/207184293) and [here(red)](https://gitlab.com/darwinsw/event.boss/-/jobs/366851125): the main difference I see is the version of the GitLab runner involved, 12.5.0-rc1 (for the red case) *vs.* 11.10.1 (for the green one)

I realize that the question is complex and the variables involved are many, so... does anyone have any suggestions on how I can try to debug this scenario? Thank you very much in advance: any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Just from the examples of pipeline execution that succeed and fail, you seem to be running different docker images (different SHAs) for `event:eventstore:latest`. They are also using different GitLab runners, but I can't imagine that would cause any problems. If your errors are network related, can there be some differences on where your tests are actually run that causes the problems? A changed version of the docker machine, or changes in their network that causes these problems?

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! Sure, there is between "red" and "green" execution the difference you pointed out. I tryied specifying explicitly eventstore version and relaunched local tests (from UI), local gitlab-runner and remote pipeline; results are green, green, red :-(

Comment: Did you manage to find something more about this one? Can there be some old data that you use in your end-to-end tests that has changed?

Comment: Hi @MrBerta, yes, I fixed my pipeline problem, identifying the root cause: it was a problem in the test cases execution order, that changes between my local environment and the GitLab pipeline. Surprisingly, the order was not the same between old and new pipeline execution, may be due a change in the GitLab runner (but Gradle version was the same...). Anyhow, I solved the problem rewriting tests so they are order-independant. Anyway, thank you for you interest!

Comment: Great to hear that you fixed the problem! In most testing frameworks, the order of execution of tests are undefined. Even if they are always executed in the same way right now, the authors of the framework might change it at any point, just as you experienced.